# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be Riemann integrable on $[c,b] $ for all $c\in(a,b).$ Thus $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be Riemann integrable on $[c,b] $ for all $c\in(a,b).$  Thus $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$

I know that if we have a bounded $f$ then the statement is true. However I wonder what happens if the function is not bounded, so for example we have

$$ f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \infty & \quad x = 0 \\
            x & \quad x > 0
        \end{array}
    \right. $$

Will, in that case, f be integrable on $[c,b]$ for all $c\in(0,b)$ but not integrable on $[0,b]$?

Comment: this $f$ is not problematic: the value at a single point does not determine the integrability. You should try replacing $x$ for $x>0$ with $1/x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: I thought about $1/x$ for $x>0$ but I don't see how it could be integrable on $(0, b]$ as the values close to zero also tend to $\infty$ or can I state it is integrable?

Comment: No it isn't integrable on $(0,b]$ or $[0,b]$. You asked for something integrable on $[c,b]$ for all $c∈(0,b)$ and *not* integrable on $[0,b]$?

Comment: Yes I did, so my problem now is that I seem not to see the difference in writing $[c,b]$ for all $c\in(0,b)$ and $(0, b]$. Do we not simply exclude 0 in both cases? After all $c$ can get very close to 0. Also, thanks for your help!

Comment: The difference is in the first case, we are always stopping some distance $c>0$ away from 0. For each distance we get a different integral, and the smaller the distance the bigger the integral, which diverges as $c→ 0$. In the second case the function is not riemann integrable, and also is not improper riemann integrable (because the improper riemann integral is a limit as $c→ 0$).

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Riemann integrable function has to be bounded, basta. Consider the example
$$f(x):={1\over\sqrt{x}}\quad(0<x\leq1),\qquad f(0):=0\ .$$
This $f$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$, but integrable on any subinterval $[c,1]$, $c>0$. Therefore the Riemann integral $\int_{[0,1]} f(x)\>{\rm d}x$ does **not** exist. Nevertheless the *improper integral*
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\>dx:=\lim_{c\to0+}\int_c^1 f(x)\>dx=\lim_{c\to0+}\bigl(2\sqrt{1}-2\sqrt{c}\bigr)$$
*converges*, and has the value $2$.